# How to select text in iterm with Shift+Arrow?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, iterm2

On most mac applications Shift+Arrow selects text but in iterm it just moves the cursor without selecting. How do you get it to select the text?

Would also be curious if there's a way to do this in terminal.app, too.

Comment: Almost similar question, maybe it can clarify your point : http://superuser.com/questions/93573/select-text-in-iterm-using-keyboard

Comment: a terminal is not like "most applications"... the entire point of a terminal application is that whatever you type is sent into the program that is running in the terminal. A program would need to be designed to do something resembling the selection of text based off of the shift+arrow keypresses. As an example: when I run Vim inside iterm, it actually does just that (though it requires custom configuration to enable that behavior). But the concept of selecting a range of text in a bash terminal shell doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 39):

[Follow the directions in this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1216606/513564) which describes using the iTerm custom key bindings to map <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to select by word. Its smart to make new key mappings in a profile to test it out, rather than the main keys preference.

#### Suggested keybindings

**iTerm:** `Preferences > Profiles > Keys`

Click `+` to add a keybinding, `Click to Set`

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>  | **Action:** Move start of selection back > Move by character

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> | **Action:** Move end of selection forward > Move by character

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>  | **Action:** Move start of selection back > Move by word

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> | **Action:** Move end of selection forward > Move by word

*your <kbd>⌘ C</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ V</kbd> will work to copy/paste these selections*

Comment: I recommend **_disabling_** `General > Selection > ✅ Automatically enter copy mode ...`

Answer (score 27):

> in iterm it just moves the cursor without selecting. How do you get it to select >the text?

Yeah, iTerm has a special technique for text selection. Takes a little getting used to, but it's way faster than the ol' "shift+arrow" mac OS method.

If the text you want to select is anywhere in your current session's scrollback, just hit `⌘`+`f` and then type the first few characters you want to select. iTerm will find the text and highlight it.

Then, hit `tab` to extend the selection to the end of the next word, repeating `tab` as many times as you need to fully select your required text.

When you're satisfied with the selection, go ahead and punch in your (`⌘`+`c`) +  (`⌘`+`V`) or what have you.

*Bonus:* You can also use `shift`+`tab` to extend your selection backwards to the start of the previous word.

Comment: Even though this isn't (I think) what the OP asked about, this is the answer to the question I have.

Answer (score 20):

To extend @merlin answer here are some more iTerm2 key bindings for navigation/deletion

<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> | send hex **0x15** | delete line

<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> | send hex **0x1B 0x08** | delete word

<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> | send hex **0x01** | move a cursor to the beginning of a line

<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> | send hex **0x05** | move a cursor to the end of a line

<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> | send esc seq **Esc+b** | move a cursor to the left by word

<kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> | send esc seq **Esc+f** | move a cursor to the right by word

<kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> | move **start** of sel **back** by **word** | select to the left by word

<kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> | move **end** of sel **forward** by **word** | select to the right by word

Comment: Shirt+Option+RightArrow/LeftArrow result in ;10C & ;10D being typed. How to make them performed as mentioned in this answer? I assume it's some setting in the preferences that I am unaware of. I will note that in my Profile "keys" settings I use "Natural Text Editing"

Comment: Here is mine [.itermkeymap](https://gist.github.com/danylokos/d2fe0b798b06b7132f935ac09044970c), but as far as I remember,  I've not changed anything in settings except the key bindings.

Answer (score 4):

All these options are viable but there's something simpler one can do. In key mappings there's a special preset called "Natural text editing" that covers the most part. You would only need to add two shortcuts for text selection.

[image]