Select to the end of the line in iTerm2
Is it possible to set up a shortcut that lets you select the text starting from the cursor location to the end of the line? I want to achieve something like CTRL + SHIFT + ->, or CMD + SHIFT + -> on MAC. I tried with the key mappings in the Profile tab inside Settings but it doesn't seem to work.
I managed to set up jumping to the end of the line, but that's not what I am looking for. I am looking for selecting the text.

Tripple click the line is probably the easiest way

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055402/how-to-select-text-in-iterm-with-shiftarrow

@0stone0 I want it to be from where the cursor is positioned, and not the whole line.
